# ValidationSummary does not showing all the error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, razor

In my page, there is a ValidationSammuery which is showing error message for two fields only even though there is error on multiple fileds.
Here is my model -

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Plan Name can't be empty")]
    public string PlanName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Short Name can't be empty")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sponsor can't be empty")]
    public string Sponsor { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public short Status { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
```

And Here is my htmlvalidation code,

```
    <div class="alert-block alert-danger">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    </div>
```

This is the output,
[image]

I can't seem to find any problem why wouldn't it show all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Bind{
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Plan Name can't be empty")]
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Short Name can't be empty")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sponsor can't be empty")]
        public string Sponsor { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
        public short Status { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PlanName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PlanName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PlanName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ShortName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ShortName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ShortName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Sponsor" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Sponsor" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Sponsor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="alert-block alert-danger">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]

As your div only shows two error messages,maybe you have style like this in your view:

```
<style>
    .validation-summary-errors ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

If your have style like this,div will only show only two messages even you have more than two error messages.So you only need to remove style like this,div will show all the error messages.

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PlanName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PlanName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PlanName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ShortName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ShortName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ShortName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Sponsor" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Sponsor" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Sponsor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="alert-block alert-danger">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .validation-summary-errors ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

result:
[image]